# .NET API + Keycloak inside of Docker never authenticate successfully

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, keycloak, docker-container

Hey I am trying to set up .NET api authentication with use of keycloak. Authentication works fine when API is not inside of the container but when I run it with use of docker-compose the result is always 401. I am quite new to docker so I used the docker-compose and docker file creation with use of VisualStudio and then I tried to do it myself, but in both cases request always returned 401.

API is created with .NET 6
Docker version is 20.10.22
Keycloak version is 20.0.3

Here are some images of my basic setup:

Program.cs

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Test.OrderApi.Settings;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();       
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
            {
                o.Authority = "http://host.docker.internal:8080/realms/test";
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };

                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();`

Dockerfile for the API

`#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["tests/TestDummyMicroservices/Test.Order.Api/Test.OrderApi.csproj", "tests/TestDummyMicroservices/Test.Order.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "tests/TestDummyMicroservices/Test.Order.Api/Test.OrderApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/tests/TestDummyMicroservices/Test.Order.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Test.OrderApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Test.OrderApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.OrderApi.dll"]`

docker-compose

`version: '3.4'

services:
  test.orderapi:
    container_name: order-api
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}testorderapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: tests/TestDummyMicroservices/Test.Order.Api/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - keycloak_network
   
  postgres_keycloak:
    container_name: postgres-keycloak
    image: postgres:14.6
    command: postgres -c 'max_connections=200'
    volumes:
      - pgdata_keycloak:/var/lib/postgressql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    ports:
      - "5436:5432"
    networks:
      - keycloak_network

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.3
    command: start-dev
    environment: 
        KC_DB: postgres
        KC_DB_URL_HOST: postgres_keycloak
        KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
        KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
        KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
        KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
        KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: test.orderapi
    links:
      - test.orderapi
    depends_on:
        postgres_keycloak:
          condition: service_healthy
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - keycloak_network

volumes:
  pgdata_keycloak:
networks:
  keycloak_network:
    driver: bridge`

docker-compose.override

`version: '3.4'
services:
  test.orderapi:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"

  test.gateway:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"`

How it looks inside of docker

[image]

Result of sending request

[image]

If you need any more information please let me know

I try to authenticate .NET web API with use of Keycloak

Comment: Please share the actual code, not the images.

Comment: Ok I updated it, sry I am new to actually posting on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured this one out you have to add ValidIssuers where you specify host.docker.internal and localhost so then authentication can see them

So I added KeyckloakSettings class which takes configuration:

```
namespace SMS.OrderApi.Settings
{
    public class KeycloakSettings
    {
        public string DockerRelamUrl { get; }
        public string AppRelamUrl { get; }

        public KeycloakSettings(IConfiguration config)
        {
            DockerRelamUrl = config.GetValue<string>("KeyCloak:DockerRelamUrl");
            AppRelamUrl = config.GetValue<string>("KeyCloak:AppRelamUrl");
        }
    }
}
```

Added settings to the config

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "KeyCloak": {
    "DockerRelamUrl": "http://host.docker.internal:8080/realms/sms",
    "AppRelamUrl": "http://localhost:8080/realms/sms"
  }
}
```

Then added new array of TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers to the JwtBearer in Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var _keycloakSettings = new KeycloakSettings(config);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
            {
                o.Authority = _keycloakSettings.DockerRelamUrl;
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };

                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[]
                {
                    _keycloakSettings.DockerRelamUrl,
                    _keycloakSettings.AppRelamUrl,
                };
            });

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application runs on posts *5201* (http) and *7201* (https).

In your docker compose file you need to forward the proper ports for http/https

```
    ports:
      - "8001:5201"
      - "8002:7201"
```

And also set keycloack in the same port in docker or adapt your connection strings to use new port (5436)